# How To Get Data From Fitbit Oauth Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, grails, oauth, fitbit

I am implementing an `OAuth` authentication for `Fitbit`. And I have done all the process. Please refer the screen shots.

for this I have code on my controller like

```
class MyController {

    def myService;

    static defaultAction = "getUserDetails"
    String subscriber_id = "1";

    def getUserDetails() {
        if (request.getParameter("completeAuthorization") != null) {
            forward(action: 'showUserInfo')
        }
        else {
            try {

                response.sendRedirect(FitBitAPI.getBean().getResourceOwnerAuthorizationURL(new LocalUserDetail("-"), grailsApplication.config.myBaseUrl + "/my/showUserInfo?completeAuthorization="));
            }
            catch (FitbitAPIException e) {
                throw new ServletException("Exception during performing authorization", e);
            }

        }
    }

    def showUserInfo() {
        /*println "${params}--------------------------------"*/
        render {params}


        APIResourceCredentials resourceCredentials = myService.getCredentials(params)
        UserInfo userInfo;
        println "=====================gggggg================================================>>>>"+resourceCredentials
        try {
            userInfo = FitBitAPI.getBean()?.getClient()?.getUserInfo(new LocalUserDetail(resourceCredentials.getLocalUserId()));
            println "===================after FitBitAPI==============================================="
            [userInfo: userInfo]
            println "===================user Info====================================================="

        } catch (FitbitAPIException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Exception during getting user info", e);
        }
        [params:params]
    }
}
```

At first I create a link on my index page and on click `getUserDetails()` call like -----
[image]

and when I click on this link Fitbit the OAuth page open like..
[image]

and after passing all the credential i have found an error --
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use fitbit4j and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

'fitbit4j' is [deprecated](https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/API+Java+Client) now but you can use [scribe-java](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) for OAuth 1.0.

Comment: You can also use [link](https://github.com/deadcyclo/fitbit4j) for forked version of fitbit4j